# how to print nested json-object without escapes and quotation marks

Tags: java, json, nested

i have a json-object named `jsonObject`

```
{
    "action":"Read",
    "infos":[
        {
            "value":0.0350661,
            "key":"first"
        }
    ]
}
```

i wanna to print the json-object to with the following form

```
{"action":"Read","infos":[{"value":0.0350661,"key":"first"}]}
```

if i use `jsonObject.toString()` method i will get

```
{"action":"Read","infos":"[{\"value\":0.0350661,\"key\":\"first\"}]"}
```

if i use `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(jsonObject.toString())` method i will get

```
{"action":"Read","infos":"[{"value":0.0350661,"key":"first"}]"}
```

if i use jackson mapper with the following code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(getDebugInfo())
```

i will get `jsonString` as

```
{"nameValuePairs":{"action":"Read","infos":[{"value":0.0350661,"key":"first"}]}}
```

is there any solution to get the desired output json-string?

Comment: Is `jackson` the only library you are willing to use, or are solutions using `gson` or other libraries also acceptable?

Comment: @Pshemo other libraries are acceptable. I searched the gson library but didn't find feasible solution, = =

Comment: You said that you have "json-object". How you create it? If it is from POJO then simple `Gson gson = new Gson(); String str = gson.toJson(myPOJO);` should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

- JSON Structure

You have that as an object, that is why quotes are not present there.

In your example, an array object is present, at the Json structure.

- Code/Java

While printing at *Console*, the json body's every Key & Value toString() are referred .

That is why the Double Quotes present, as Strings are getting used!

Comment: i known it, but i wanna get the unqueted version of json-string

Comment: that would mean an object ! I highly doubt, that being possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have tried the below code using GSON library, and it is printing me the correct json as shown above.

```
public static void main ( String [] args ) {

        JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject.addProperty("action", "Read");
        JsonArray jsonArr = new JsonArray();
        JsonObject jsonObject2 = new JsonObject();
        jsonObject2.addProperty("value", 0.0350661);
        jsonObject2.addProperty("key", "first");
        jsonArr.add(jsonObject2);
        jsonObject.add("infos", jsonArr);


        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        JsonElement json = gson.fromJson(jsonString,JsonElement.class);
        String jsonInString = gson.toJson(json);
        System.out.println(jsonInString);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
{
  "action": "Read",
  "infos": [
    {
      "value": 0.0350661,
      "key": "first"
    }
  ]
}
```

Even if I am forming the jsonObject using `org.json`, and simple printing it using `System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());` on console, m getting the result like this.

```
{"action":"Read","infos":[{"value":0.0350661,"key":"first"}]}
```

So here, not sure how you have formed your jsonObject.